# How to count observations per ID in R?

Tags: r

I have a large amount of Data where I have to count meassurments per one ID. What I already did was creating a Data Frame over all Files and I omited the NAs. This part works properly. I was wondering if the nrow-function is the right function to solve this but I figured out that this will not lead me to the target as it returns a single number as output.

What I am looking for is if you have entries like that:

```
1155 2010-05-02  2.7200    1
1156 2010-05-05  2.6000    3
1157 2010-05-08  2.6700    1
1158 2010-05-11  3.5700    2
```

That I get a list:

```
ID          Number of observations
1           2
2           1
3           1
```

Comment: Just use `table(Data$ID)` or `as.data.frame(table(Data$ID))` if you want a `data.frame` back.

Comment: I think this question should be better posted on other general programming spaces like Stack Overflow

Answer (score 5):

Using the `data.table` structure (see the [wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki)),

```
library(data.table)
D <- data.table(x = c(1155, 1156, 1157, 1158),
                date = as.Date(c("2010-05-02", "2010-05-05", "2010-05-08", "2010-05-11")),
                y = c(2.7200, 2.6000, 2.6700, 3.5700),
                id = c(1, 3, 1, 2))
counts <- D[, .(rowCount = .N), by = id]
counts
```

This will return

```
counts
##    id rowCount
## 1:  1        2
## 2:  3        1
## 3:  2        1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is simply with the "table" function.

```
ids<-c(1,3,1,2)
counts<-data.frame(table(ids))
counts
```

Answer (score 1):

OK if I understood correctly you can do something like:

```
df$observations <- rep(1, nrow(df))
df <- df[ ,-file_name_column]
new_data <- data.frame(aggregate(df, by= ID, FUN=sum))
```

Caution: this might not work exactly since I am not sure what you data frame looks like.

Answer (score 1):

aggregate() should work, as the previous answer suggests. Another option is with the [plyr package](http://plyr.had.co.nz/):

```
count(yourDF,c('id'))
```

Using more columns in the vector with 'id' will subdivide the count.

I believe ddply() (also part of plyr) has a summarize argument which can also do this, similar to aggregate().

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Jeremy's but using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
mytable <-
"a    date        b         id
 1155 2010-05-02  2.7200    1
 1156 2010-05-05  2.6000    3
 1157 2010-05-08  2.6700    1
 1158 2010-05-11  3.5700    2"

mytable <- read.delim(textConnection(mytable), header=TRUE,  sep="")
mytable %>% count(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Function [`rle`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/rle) is also great to do that if you don't want to download `dplyr`:

```
rle(as.vector(mytable$id))
rle(as.vector(mytable$id))$lengths
```